# Only build jar, then delete all folders

Tags: java, maven

When I run

```
$ mvn install
```

It build the project into a jar, but it leaves behind a load of junk folders as well:

```
$ ls
./          archive-tmp/        generated-sources/  maven-status/
../         classes/            maven-archiver/     project-0.0.1.jar
dir1/
```

How do I build a maven project so that all the junk directories aren't there, only the jar file?

*EDIT*: note that I don't want *all* folders to be removed (`dir1` in the above example), just the maven-related ones.

Comment: `mvn clean install && mvn clean`. This will **install** the jar into the local repo and clean up after itself.

Comment: @BoristheSpider `mvn clean` deletes _all_ folders though, I only want the maven-related ones to be removed

Comment: It installs it into the local repo before deleting, that was my point. As far as I am aware what you want is not possible for all sorts of reasons.

Comment: @BoristheSpider no, I already tried `mvn clean install` and it just deletes everything

Comment: Please re-read my comment. Maven `install` _installs_ the artefacts into the [**local Maven repository**](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html). Of course `clean` deletes all files in `target`. Maven is designed to place artefacts in the repo, target is a temporary workspace.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I'd accept an answer that simply shows how I can separate where the jar is built to from where all these other folders are dumped

Comment: What about `mvn clean install clean`?

Comment: @minseong Could you give us a short explanation _why_ you want to do this? If you want to reuse the jar for other projects, you would take them from the local repository and not from target, so you don't actually need it in target.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make much sense, but to answer your question, you may override how cleaning is handled:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.1</version>
    <configuration>

        <excludeDefaultDirectories>true</excludeDefaultDirectories>

        <filesets>

            <fileset>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
            </fileset>
            <fileset>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-test-sources</directory>
            </fileset>

            <fileset>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/...</directory>
            </fileset>

        </filesets>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Gross. Would work I suppose. Other developers may beat you round the head with a (large and heavy) Maven book for this however. Use at own risk...

Comment: hehe.. Should I delete it ? It sure doesn't feel right...and I don't want to be beaten with large and heavy stuff!

Comment: nope, OT specificaly requests this beat-me solution

Comment: Agree, shouldn't be deleted. Is a good answer to a stupid question.

Comment: Why is the question stupid? I don't get what the purpose of the extra generated directories are.

Comment: My personal opinion: I prefer to stick with maven standard behaviour. Someone else may checkout your project, add some plugin performing some *repackaging* plugin/task and wonder why generated-sources aren't considered, only to realize that the maven working directories were emptied at every build (or some folders aren't removed when calling `clean`). The default behaviour: keep the working files until `clean` is called. `clean` removes everything from target, so that the next build is guaranteed to be fresh! The artifacts are *installed* in the local .m2 folder, so it's ok to clean.